# How to increase FUSION-LTK lidar processing productivity?

Tags: lidar, fusion

I am processing Lidar data with [FUSION-LTK](http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/fusion/fusionlatest.html).  My study area contains 5 blocks of 1000 las tiles per block.  Each block is broken into approximately 4 subblocks of 250 las tiles.  I am calculating grid metrics and strata metrics to assess vegetation structure.  I wrote simple batch files to process entire blocks (e.g. block 1 subblock1; block 1 subblock2;...) using the command line tools in FUSION-LTK.

The problem I am encountering is that I am only able to process one subblock at a time.  When I try to simultaneously start processing on another block, the current session of FUSION-LTK stops the processing and moves to the new block.  How can I improve the processing workflow so that more than one subblock are processed simultaneously, or at least enhance the multiprocessing capabilities of LTK?

Comment: I ll be doing something similar in the coming weeks, i'll let you know what i come up with, but you could alway spawn instances of the same process with a simple python multithreaded script, similary like the famous generate_tiles.py script for mapnik.

Comment: Hi Aaron, have you found any solution to your question? Have you tried to use the Fusion's LTKprocessor to optimize the tasks? See the [example 4](http://www.fs.fed.us/eng/rsac/lidar_training/Forest_Inventory_Modeling/story_content/external_files/exer4_gridmetrics.pdf), in Fusion's tutorial, for example.

Comment: Unfortunately, not @AndreSilva. Yes, I use LTK, though find the GUI cumbersome. I have been porting some lidar functionality over to python, however, FUSION seems to be the only available application for grid metrics.